# How I can use swagger.json from editor.swagger.io in my Django+drf-yasg project?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I integrate drf-yasg in my project, generate json file: `python manage.py generate_swagger swagger.json`. After that I edit my swagger.json in [editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io/) and export it. And now, how i can use this manually created swagger.json file in my project instead autogenerate? Thanks.